# Probablity/Statistical Inference Important Questions (problems) Collection for Interviews and Understanding of Concept

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, statistical-inference, book-recommendation

This might be irrelevant here! But I would really appreciate your help! It would definitely help lot of us preparing for Interviews in Data Science domain.

I am looking for a book/github/ any resource where I can find Probablity & STatistical Inference questions/puzzles (just like leetcode has programming) to prepare for interviews.

Any suggestions on books/resources which has probablity problems I can solve to get thorough on all sort of probablity and statistical inference questions.

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if you know of [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/) or not but it has various puzzles and questions on probability and statistics, among many other topics in mathematics and science. The first few sections of every course are free as well

Comment: Yea! I have seen Brilliant.org.. Any other resources?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are no resources yet for data science/machine learning interviews that are on par with [Cracking the Coding Interview](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0984782850), [Heard on the Street](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0994138695) or [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/).

There are various websites that collect interview questions, but they usually do not provide detailed answers. Here are some examples:
[100+ Data Science and Machine Learning Interview Questions](https://www.learndatasci.com/data-science-interview-questions/)
[Curated list of 70 data science interview questions](https://www.interviewqs.com/blog/practice_data_science_interview_questions)
[How to Prepare for a Machine Learning Interview](https://semanti.ca/blog/?how-to-prepare-for-a-machine-learning-interview)
[Acing AI Interviews](https://medium.com/acing-ai/acing-ai-interviews/home)
[100+ Basic Deep Learning Interview Questions and Answers](http://theprofessionalspoint.blogspot.com/2019/06/100-basic-deep-learning-interview.html?m=1)

This [Stats.SE thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5465/statistics-interview-questions) is also relevant.

For probability questions you can rely on quantitative finance books such as Heard on the Street and the likes.